# Selenium Grid Demo Test cases fail

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am using selenium grid for automated testing. I have followed the official documents to install the grid. But after running the run-demo-in-parallel, the test casses fail with the following error in the target folder.

```
Parameter #1    Parameter #2    Parameter #3    Parameter #4
localhost   4444    *firefox    http://images.google.com

**Could not contact Selenium Server; have you started it on 'localhost:4444'** ?
 Read       more at http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/not-started.html   Connection refused: connect
 com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:86)
 at    com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.tools.ThreadSafeSeleniumSessionStorage.startSeleniumSession(ThreadSafeSeleniumSessionStorage.java:26)at com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.demo.WebTestForASingleBrowser.domme(WebTestForASingleBrowser.java:51)
```

Can you please tell me what the issue can be ?
 I am using a windows7 machine.
 With java jdk and jre 1.6. Selenium version 1.0.8 . Selenium stand alone server -2.5.0.
 Is there any more information i can give ?

Comment: afeSeleniumSessionStorage closeSeleniumSession
     [java] INFO: Closing Selenese session: com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSel
enium@6156d8
     [java]
     [java] ===============================================
     [java] Selenium Grid Demo In Parallel
     [java] Total tests run: 4, Failures: 4, Skips: 0
     [java] ===============================================
     [java]

BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files\Java\selenium-grid-1.0.8\build.xml:137: Java returned: 1

Total time: 3 minutes 58 seconds

C:\Program Files\Java\selenium-grid-1.0.8>ant run-demo-in-parallel

Comment: Above is the command promt out put for ant run-demo-in-parallel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open up taskmanager and see if there is a process with the name java.exe or javaw.exe running if that is  not the case then your Sel Grid has not yet been started. Please open (double click) the `selenium-server-standalone-2.5.0.jar` file then again statup taskmanager and make sure your grid is up and running and then try.

if the process is nt started It might be the case that your grid is not able to start to some reason I would suggest opening up a command prompt window and run the following command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.5.0.jar -role hub
```

Note: You need to be in the directory where the jar file is for the above command to work else cmd will throw an error saying file not found

Please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot !!!!! "launch hub" command was not working for some reason.
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.5.0.jar -role hub worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm following the demo and it hasn't said anything about the selenium standalone server?