# Selenium grid unable to run the demo test

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, demo

Okay, this is my first ever try to run the Selenium Grid.

1 - I went according this page: http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/run_the_demo.html

```
 ant launch-hub
 ant launch-remote-control
 ant run-demo-in-sequence
```

Ofcourse, every command in different MS-DOS window (Running windows XP)]

I see everything as demo suggests, up to the last point where I see just this:

```
run-demo-in-sequence:
 [java] [Parser] Running:
 [java]   Selenium Grid Demo In Sequence
 [java]
 [java] 21-Mar-2012 14:46:29 com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.tools.ThreadSafeSeleniumSessionStorage startSeleniumSession
 [java] INFO: Contacting Selenium RC at localhost:4444
```

New window of firefox does come up but thats it. I waited like 10 minutes and nothing happened.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331931/selenium-grid-demo-test-cases-fail) on SO, which did not help me at all.

Because this is freshly installed, I am going to try to restart computer to see if it helps, but other help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT**
Restarting of the computer did not help. I tried also running demo in paralel, with same result - four new firefox windows appear and nothing happens.

ANT:

```
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.3 compiled on February 26 2012
```

Selenium grid version: 1.0.8

Firefox version 11.0

**EDIT 2**
OK, stupid me - the demo references that I will find the source codes in `demo` subfolder. Since I cannot find the demo subfolder ... that could be the issue, right? :)

**EDIT 3**
I checked older version of selenium grid and it does not contain the `demo` subfolder also. Ok, I am stuck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium version 1.0.8 doesn't support FF 11.0. You should use Grid 2.0 . Thats the latest. You can find details [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2)

Comment: Not my day really :) I get to the point where you start node and...
INFO: Launching a selenium grid node
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.String.isEmpty()Z
        at org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest.getRemoteControlConfiguration(RegistrationRequest.java:585)
        at org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.SelfRegisteringRemote.startRemoteServer(SelfRegisteringRemote.java:86)
        at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher.main(GridLauncher.java:72)

Comment: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register

Comment: Did you start the hub and are you able to see the hub console @ http://localhost:4444/grid/console?

Comment: yes, I did. Thats why this confuses me. Anyways, I am thinking about starting new question, because this answer was successful to the original question

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of Selenium is failed to control firefox version 11.0 you should try with firefox 10 or prior versions.

Comment: how do I do that? Uninstall firefox? Or can I direct it to the bin? Since I know how to start Webdriver, this is completly new to me...

Comment: Yes, You may uninstall firefox and install firefox 10. Or you may google to find the way to degrade firefox version w/o uninstalling. But I would suggest uninstall current firefox and install older version.